# Asus 1018p dead after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, boot-failure, asus, bios

I was successfully running 11.10 and upgraded through the software update. Everything was running perfectly until i did a reboot. Now when i hit the power button the light comes on and the wireless indicator light comes on, but nothing else. I have tried to boot from usb, i have tried to boot into the bios, i have tried every hot key startup combo in the manual and i still get nothing... any ideas??

Comment: So you can't even get into the bios?  Pull the battery to kill the power for a minute.

Comment: tried that. Left the battery out for several min... no change

Comment: The Hard drive light will flash for a microsecond but it never begins spinning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm worried that you can't even see a BIOS screen. That's not good...

I know this may not be the best or most likely solution. But if you are familiar with how to handle RAM, take the plug and battery out of your machine, then carefully remove the RAM. Then place it back in. See if that does any good.

Comment: Another step to try if that doesn't work. Remove the hard drive all together. Keep RAM in. Boot up, see if it gives you an error that the HDD is missing.

Comment: giving the RAM removal a try now

Comment: the RAM and is out... does it matter how long i leave it out?

Comment: Nope, just pop it out, then back in. 
If you have more than one, make sure they are all out before you put any back in.

Comment: Wow... it worked... reseated the RAM and i am rolling like nothing ever happened... question is, how do i figure out what went wrong/prevent it from happening again?

Comment: I'm very happy it worked. 
Generally, when your computer doesn't even get to a BIOS state, it's potentially a memory problem (at least you want it to be lol... otherwise it could be expensive or very complicated).

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help. Saved my butt. Really, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In that case i would try to unload all memory by removing the battery and power supply for some time.
Sometimes a bad programmed ACPI is producing such bad results. You have to make sure, that the PC is "forgetting" everything.